# Microsoft Access VBA, compact n repair, database corrupted

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a table with 1.5 million records and i need to make a lot of modification to the data.

As i need to automate the whole process, i am trying to put all the steps under one command button by calling all the sub at one time.

However,due to the size of the data, the size of the access database will hit 2GB(the max limit) after running one subroutine or cant even finish running one subroutine.

I have attached one sub which often lead to corruption of the database as the file size will hit 2GB halfway, and then stop running.

I really need help on this, will appreciate anyone's help!

```
Sub cogsinout()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Final")

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
  If (rs!El = "BA") Or (rs!El= "BE") Or (rs!El = "FE") Or (rs!El = "LA") Or (rs!El = "LB") Or (rs!El Then
     rs.Edit
     rs!cogs = "COGS IN"
     rs.Update
    Else

             rs.Edit
     rs!cogs = "COGS OUT"
     rs.Update

   End If
   rs.MoveNext
   Loop

   End Sub
```

Comment: If you show own effort on the error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197224/access-vba-runtime-error-3052-file-sharing-lock-count-exceeded, I we will sovle that too. Did you compact the db? What is its size then?

Comment: The size of the access database file is 500Mb before running the sub, but it will hit 2GB after running, i tried to use array to shorten my code, but the error still exist.

Comment: What did I told you about my answer? Also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: No trouble, just struggle caused ;) Don't forget to search on former question and delete your last comment (Thanks should be deleted after recognized to keep comments clean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try updating the table with this function,
It seems that in this method the database is less bloating.

```
Sub cogsinoutNew()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database: Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "UPDATE Final SET cogs = 'COGS OUT' WHERE El Not In ('BA','BE','FE','LA','LB');"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

strSQL = "UPDATE Final SET cogs = 'COGS IN' WHERE El In ('BA','BE','FE','LA','LB');"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```